# Two functions in one onclick - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to execute two functions at once validating online form. First form works fine but the second is not being executed. Can anyone point out what is wrong with my code?

```
function both(){
    validation();
    regex();
}

function validation(){
    var valid = true;
    var error = [];

    if (document.check_in.forename.value == ""){
        error.push("First Name");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (document.check_in.surname.value == ""){
        error.push("Surname");
        valid = false;
}
    if (valid == false) {
        alert("Please fill in the following fields:\n" + error.join("\n") + ".");
    }
    return valid;
}

function regex(){
    var fnameRE = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
var valid_reg = true; 
    var error_reg = [];

    if (!fnameRE.test(document.check_in.forname.value)) {
        error_reg.push("Please use characters only in First Name field.");
        valid_reg = false;
    }   
    else if (valid_reg == false) {
        alert("Please fill s:\n" + error_reg.join("\n") + ".");
    }
    return valid_reg;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<form name="check_in" method="POST" action="form.html" onSubmit="return both()">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like

```
function both(){
    return (validation() && regex())
}
```

This way "both" will return `true` only if both function passed validation. Otherwise it returns `false`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this might be it....you are calling two functions with return statement in both, as soon as it encounters the first return statement, your code execution ends. Did you try putting an alert in your `regex()` function? Can you try that and prove my statement right/wrong here.

your workaround:

```
function both(){
    var valid = validation();
    var regexvalid = regex();

    if(valid && regexvalid)
          return true;
    else
          return false;
}
```